# Upload image and reload page don't show the image in angular 2

Tags: angular

I´m trying to show an image after upload and reload the page, but for some reason when I reload the page, image return a `404 error (not found)`. Let me explain you better.

1. User can upload and save an image. **This works**
2. User can see the image after upload. **This works**.
3. If for some reason, browser reloads, image needs to be shown again. NOT WORKING!

**editComponent.ts**

```
//Set default image
public showChildThumb:SafeUrl = this.config.uploadFolder + this.config.defaultImgThumb;

ngOnInit(){
    //get Url Param
    this.route.params.take(1)
    .map(user => {
        ... some stuff...
        return param['id']
    })
    .map(param => {
        return this.store$.select('user').takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$)
        .map(user => {
            ... Some stuff ...
            if(this.editMode){

                this.showChildThumb = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.config.uploadFolder +'/'+ user.childs[param].picture);

            }

        }).subscribe()
    }).subscribe()
}
```

**editComponent.html**

```
<img [src]="showChildThumb" alt="" #imgThumb class="img-fluid">
```

See the problem [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gALekr4hi1o) (Animated gif)

I already tried to adding a query to the url `./assets/uploads/thumb.png?ramdomNumber` to see if there is a cache problem but same result.

**UPDATE FOR ANSWER BELOW QUESTIONS**

I'm using NODE, EXPRESS, MongoDb, angularCLI, angular 2+

I'm using `ng2-file-upload` module to upload image and `multer` module in node.

All the process of uploading, saving and store the image in folder is doing ok.

As I mention when I run the app the image shows, and the URL is

```
<img _ngcontent-c13="" alt="" class="img-fluid" src="blob:http://localhost:4200/3c36e668-2cfb-403f-a2a1-4095e6f42975">
```

but when I **upload** and then **reload** the page, the response is 404 error

Any help?

Link to see the problem updated (Youtube)

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the URL of the image ? If u access it from web address does it work ? I mean do u get 200 ok ?

Comment: and how do you actually upload it? what type of server?

Comment: 1-be sue that image saved successfully in folder
2-print image URL after upload
3-print image URl after refresh
4-be sure URL after upload like URL after refresh